# Does scanf break on gigantic char tables?

Tags: c, scanf, arrays

I have a problem with reading string of triples digit-digit-space.

Relevant code (lib's may / may not be needed in this particular code):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 20
#define M 20
#define n (3*N*M)

int main()
{
        char str_t[n];

        scanf("%s", str_t);

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%c", str_t[i]);
        return 0;
}
```

The input is as mentioned set of triples repeated 399 times finished with d-d, saved to char array[1200].

I assume that pasting into console is okay since I did it before. When it comes to printing back the array, I get random mumbo jumbo like: 3�X2���W2��@M!�

Input:

> 08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08 49 49 99
>   40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00 81 49 31 73 55 79
>   14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65 52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69
>   24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91 22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54
>   22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80 24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84
>   20 35 17 12 50 32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38
>   64 70 67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21 24
>   55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72 21 36 23 09
>   75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95 78 17 53 28 22 75 31
>   67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92 16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58
>   88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57 86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44
>   60 21 58 51 54 17 58 19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77
>   04 89 55 40 04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98
>   66 88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69 04 42
>   16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36 20 69 36 41 72
>   30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16 20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01
>   74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54 01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33
>   48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48

Comment: scanf stops on spaces and on newlines and does not append a '\0' character to strings.  The str_t buffer is not initialized to any specific value (preferably 0x00) so contains garbage.  the scanf is only going to read 2 characters, then the printf will print from the beginning of str_t until a '\0' byte is encountered.  If such byte value is not encountered in the str_t buffer, then several things can happen including a seg fault event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf, concerning the `%s` format:

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters... The input string
>   stops at white space

Comment: I am officially an idiot. Whatever I'd sit editing code if I didn't ask.

Comment: Note: "The input string stops at white space" is true _after_ it has matched some non-white-space characters.  Leading white-space is consumed first and then matching of non-white-space characters commences.

Answer (score 1):

If the input consists of a single line, you can use `fgets` instead of `scanf`:

```
fgets(str_t, n, stdin);
```

Comment: please do not recommend gets as it's a totally unsafe function. fgets is a better choice

Comment: @Laurijssen Thanks for your comment! I modified the answer.